# Using the Qt library in an existing c++ VS2010 program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

I'm trying to get the the Qt library to work in an my existing VS2010 project. But I am pretty much stuck.

I have succesuflly compiled the library with nmake on 64 bit and added the Qt adon for vs2010.

But i don't no how to use it in my project, the project makes already use of the boost and the opencv librarys and these work just fine.

I found a thread here on stackoverflow that says I need to edit the vs project file with an text editor but when I do this I cant find the global section that I need to edit.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you really mean "exciting"? Or should it be "existing"? There is normally no need to edit the project files manually. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I mean existing, soory for the error. The question is how do i call the library in my existing project? So that i don't need to create a new QT project.

Comment: If you are sendign Qt events around you will probably need a QApplication running see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150488/using-a-qt-based-dll-in-a-non-qt-application

Comment: I tried to make a new QT project (with one form) but then VS says there is no 64x version assigned to qt. But i build it with the vs 64x command promt. There is also just one version of qt that the plugin sees(qt->options). Does someone knows what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, wel sort of. I made a new QT project and added my excisting code in the new QT project. I also linked the opencv an boost libs and the application works now!

Thanks for all the comments