# Use a Qt made library in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I created a shared library with Qt Creator (compiler MSVC2010 32bits) to make some operations with xml files (when I had to select the modules, I checked QtCore, QtXml and QtXmlPatterns).

Here is the code of the lib :

Header :

```
#ifndef CONVERTERSHARED_H
#define CONVERTERSHARED_H

#include "convertershared_global.h" //created automatically by Qt
#include <QString>

class CONVERTERSHAREDSHARED_EXPORT ConverterShared
{
public:
    ConverterShared();
    bool convert(QString inFileName);
};

#endif // CONVERTERSHARED_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "convertershared.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDir>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QMap>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ConverterShared::ConverterShared()
{
}

bool ConverterShared::convert(QString inFileName)
{
//process...
}
```

So it creates a .lib, and a .dll.

When I use this lib in a Qt project (including paths to includes, libraries in .pro, putting .dll in the exe directory), all is fine, I can create an instance of ConverterShared and use the convert function.

My problem is to use it in a Visual Studio (C++ 2010) project which doesn't use Qt. So in the properties of the project, I added :

- in C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> path/to/convertershared.h (contains convertershared_global.h too)
- in Libraries -> General -> Additional Dependencies -> ConverterShared.lib (tested with path/ConverterShared.lib and without path)
- in Libraries ->General -> Additional Libraries Directories -> path/to/lib

Then, in a .cpp file, it finds convertershared.h so I include it but when I compile, I get the error :

```
Cannot open include file QtCore/qglobal.h: No such file or directory
(and then IntelliSense cannot open source file "QtCore/qglobal.h", "QString")
```

So how to correct that and use my Qt lib in a Visual project which doesn't use Qt (the PC on which the final Visual project is compiled doesn't necessarly have Qt installed)?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need define the path to Qt include files, such us qglobal.h etc., which referenced from your `convertershared_global.h` file. For instance, in VS project's properties page `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories` add `$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore` and other paths, if necessary, to make the compiler find all includes.

Comment: Indeed, defining the path to Qt solves the error but it still requires Qt installed on the PC.

Comment: @SteveTJS, You will not be able to run that program without Qt libraries anyways. And I think you need them to link your program too.

Comment: So I will rephrase my question : how to deploy a Qt library just like you can deploy Qt application providing only Qt dlls?

Comment: @SteveTJS, I don't think there is a defined method. You simply need to identify your project's dependencies and copy only those Qt files (headers, libs, dlls) you need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In my case I had to add $(QTDIR)\include (instead of $(QTDIR)\include\QtCore) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you link your application with a shared library that uses Qt, you should also link your application with Qt and define the include paths. Even if you link with Qt, your application needs an instance of `QCoreApplication` and also an event loop to work.

In your case since you don't have a Qt application and want to link to a Qt shared library you can create an instance of the `QCoreApplication` in a new thread in your shared library and then run the event loop as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222584/how-to-create-a-qt-shared-library-for-a-non-qt-application/27969425#27969425).

If don't want to link your application with Qt, you can load your shared library at runtime and dynamically call it's functions using `QLibrary` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795087/c-load-shared-library-and-extract-class-implementations-at-runtime-on-linux-pl/22795461#22795461).

Comment: QLibrary sounds good but it seems that it still requires Qt to be installed on the PC, doesn't it?

Comment: Definitely you need Qt libraries. But as i mentioned you need an event loop even if you link to Qt and provide the libraries.