# Using QT widgets in DLL

Tags: qt, dll, qwidget

I want to call QMessageBox in one of the methods in my shared library, but when I'm trying to do that, I get "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget". But I can't construct QApplication in my shared library, so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Normally, you'd need to instantiate an instance of QApplication and then call exec() to run the GUI UI thread (main event loop). This sounds like a duplicate of something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150488/using-a-qt-based-dll-in-a-non-qt-application  .  The answer to the question is a bit old (2010) so you'd have to do a bit more research with Qt 5.xx.xx and beyond

Comment: Why you cant construct QApplication in your library?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: libraries shouldn't (usually) have a QApplication context, as they're usually included into a QApplication context.

Comment: @NicholasSmith it depends on application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say avoid creating QMessageBox (or any GUI widgets) within a shared library as it dilutes the purpose, what if you used the library with a non-GUI application?

The solution I use frequently with shared libraries is to use the signal/slots system, and then allow the QApplication to manage how it wants to display the result on screen, so emit a signal and connect it to a slot within your application that displays the QMessageBox.