# Error when calling quit() on a QCoreApplication within a QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qcoreapplication

In an effort to create a Qt event loop in a separate thread, from within a DLL which is called by a main application written in Java, I have done the following, based on a suggestion I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150488/using-a-qt-based-dll-in-a-non-qt-application), which works rather well:

```
// Define a global namespace. We need to do this because the parameters 
// passed to QCoreApplication must have a lifetime exceeding that of the 
// QCoreApplication object
namespace ToolThreadGlobal
{
    static int argc = 1;
    static char * argv[] = { "MyVirtualMainApplication.exe", NULL };
    static QCoreApplication *coreApp = nullptr;
    static ToolThread *toolThread = nullptr;
};

//! The ToolThread class differs from a standard QThread only 
//! in its run() method
class ToolThread : public QThread
{
    //! Override QThread's run() method so that it calls 
    //! the QCoreApplication's exec() method rather than 
    //! the QThread's own
    void run() { ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp -> exec(); }
};

class ThreadStarter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //! Constructor
    ThreadStarter()
    {
        // Set up the tool thread:
        if (!ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread)
        {
            ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread = new ToolThread();
            connect(ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread, &ToolThread::started,
                    this, &ThreadStarter::createApplication, Qt::DirectConnection);
                    // The thread's 'started' event is emitted after the thread
                    // is started but before its run() method is invoked. By 
                    // arranging for the createApplication subroutine to be 
                    // called before run(), we ensure that the required 
                    // QCoreApplication object is instantiated *within the 
                    // thread* before ToolThread's customised run() method 
                    // calls the application's exec() command.
            ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread->start();
        }
    }

    //! Destructor
    ~ThreadStarter()
    {
        // Ensure that the thread and the QCoreApplication are cleanly 
        // shut down:
        ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp -> quit();
        delete ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp;
        ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp = nullptr;
        delete ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread;
        ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread = nullptr;
    }

    //! Function to return a pointer to the actual tool thread:
    ToolThread* getThread() const { return ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread;  }

private:
    //! Create the QCoreApplication that will provide the tool 
    //! thread's event loop
    /*! This subroutine is intended to be called from the tool 
        thread itself as soon as the thread starts up.
    */
    void createApplication()
    {
        // Start the QCoreApplication event loop, so long as no 
        // other Qt event loop is already running
        if (QCoreApplication::instance() == NULL)
        {
            ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp = new QCoreApplication(ToolThreadGlobal::argc, 
                                                             ToolThreadGlobal::argv);
        }
    }
};
```

To use this, a subroutine called from the main Java applications’ thread just needs to create a ThreadStarter object
which will automatically create a ToolThread with a QCoreApplication running inside it:

```
itsThreadStarter = new ThreadStarter();
itsToolThread = itsThreadStarter -> getThread();
```

We can then instantiate a QObject class in the usual way, move it to the thread and call its methods asynchronously using QMetaObject::invokeMethod:

```
itsWorker = new Worker();
itsWorker -> moveToThread(itsToolThread);

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(itsWorker, “doSomethingInteresting”);
```

When we’re done, we just delete the ThreadStarter object and everything is cleaned up nicely. Apart from the annoying message saying

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread
```

on startup, it seems to meet all my requirements.

Except… (and here, at last, is my question).

Occasionally - and without any pattern that I’ve been able to discern so far - I get an error during the shutdown process. Usually it occurs at the line

```
        delete ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp;
```

but sometimes at the line

```
    ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp -> exec();
```

(which of course is executed in the thread’s run() method and doesn’t return until after ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp -> quit(); has been fully executed).

Often the error message is a simple access violation; sometimes it’s a rather more involved:

```
ASSERT failure in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren(): "isDeletingChildren already set, did this function recurse?", file ..\qtbase\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.cpp, line 1927
```

I assume it’s because, once I issue the quit() command to the QCoreApplication, I should be waiting for a little while for it to close down the event loop properly before deleting it - just as one would usually call quit() and then wait() on an ordinary QThread before deleting it. However, QCoreApplication doesn’t seem to have the equivalent of a wait() command, and I can’t implement a QTimer to force a delay because it wouldn’t work once I’ve closed down the event loop with quit(). I’m therefore at a loss what to do. I have an inkling that, as QCoreApplication is a QObject, I could call its deleteLater() method but I can’t see where I should call it from.

Is there an expert out there who understands the ins and outs of QCoreApplication and QThread well enough to suggest a solution to this? Or is there a fundamental flaw in the way that I have designed this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Stop the whole process or delete the Qt part? quit() stops the whole process and I don't see why you would want to do *anything* after calling that. I would assume any delete operations after quit() to be redundant. "isDeletingChildren already set" sounds exactly like that.

Comment: What I want is to stop the separate Qt thread while the rest of the Java application carries on running, while leaving things in a state where I can start a new Qt thread at a later time. In other words, I'd like to get to a point where the two pointers in the ToolThreadGlobal namespace are null again, without any error messages having been thrown out along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me...

Firstly, I add a static 'cleanup' function to my global namespace:

```
namespace ToolThreadGlobal
{
    static int argc = 1;
    static char * argv[] = { "MyVirtualMainApplication.exe", NULL };
    static QCoreApplication *coreApp = nullptr;
    static ToolThread *toolThread = nullptr;
    static void cleanup() { coreApp->deleteLater();  coreApp = nullptr; }
};
```

Then, from my ThreadStarter::createApplication slot I connect the QCoreApplication's aboutToQuit signal to it:

```
    void createApplication()
    {
        // Start the QCoreApplication event loop, so long as no other Qt event loop
        // is already running
        if (QCoreApplication::instance() == NULL)
        {
            ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp = new QCoreApplication(ToolThreadGlobal::argc, 
                                                             ToolThreadGlobal::argv);
            connect(ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit,
                    ToolThreadGlobal::cleanup);
        }
    }
```

Then the 'ThreadStarter' destructor is reduced to just five lines (including the addition of calls to QThread::quit() and QThread::wait() which should have been there the first time around):

```
    ~ThreadStarter()
    {
        // Ensure that the thread and the QCoreApplication are cleanly shut down:
        ToolThreadGlobal::coreApp -> quit();
        ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread -> quit();
        ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread -> wait();
        delete ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread;
        ToolThreadGlobal::toolThread = nullptr;
    }
```

When the ThreadStarter destructor calls QCoreApplication::quit(), the QCoreApplication calls the cleanup function while its event loop is still running. This schedules the QCoreApplication to delete itself once it is good and ready, and in the meantime resets the global pointer to NULL so that the rest of the application knows that a new QCoreApplication can be instantiated when needed.

I guess this leaves a very small risk that there could be a conflict if the main application immediately creates a new QCoreApplication and tries to run exec() on it while the old QCoreApplication is still in the process of cleaning itself up. I don't think that is likely to happen in the context where I'm using it.