# QCoreApplication in static library loaded by MFC application

Tags: qt, mfc

I am trying to create a library that handles downloading files using QNetworkAccessManager. It is written in Qt and will be used in a large MFC project.

I am running into the issue that the signal/slot functionality in the Qt part does not work because it requires an event-loop in form of example QCoreApplication.

I have tried to create wrappers with both QThread and QEventLoop but they seem to require for example QCoreApplication in order to work. Is there any good way of solving this issue? Is there some solution in which I can create a QCoreApplication object inside the of the MFC application? (this would surely create a multitude of issues I assume).

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025168/event-loop-in-qt-based-dll-in-a-non-qt-application