# Can I use Qt network module without QCoreApplication?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, smtp, qcoreapplication

[Does Qt-based dll can be used by another non qt-based app (without QApplication)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561669/does-qt-based-dll-can-be-used-by-another-non-qt-based-app-without-qapplication)
in that post I asked a question, but topic was marked as duplicate without any reason.
I wish to know that, does Qt-based DLL (that use Qt network module) works without QCoreApplication or not? Using the QCoreApplication is prohibited!
I'm using waitForConnected/waitForReadyRead/waitForBytesWritten/waitForEncrypted functions for sockets and I need to know is that DLL will works or I must to use any other library (POCO, libcurl, VMime or something else). QCoreApplication absence is the key condition of Qt-framework usage in that case (or I must rewrite the code without Qt).

Comment: I think you'll need to explain *why* you can't use `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: Do you realize that if the application using your library has no `QCoreApplication`, you can create it *inside* your library? If it is prohibited to create `QCoreApplication` inside the library, you really need to explain why are things arranged so. Basically, without `QCoreApplication` there are no Qt event loops and hence no working signals-slots.

Comment: DLL can be used in many different applications, qt-based for example. And how can I instantiate QCoreApplication if application, that uses DLL, already have the instance?

Comment: The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150488/using-a-qt-based-dll-in-a-non-qt-application) explains how to do precisely that -- check the return value from [`QCoreApplication::instance()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#instance) and act accordingly.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: When I create an instance of QCoreApplication in my DLL, I need to call QCoreApplication::exec() for processing events etc. But calling this method will freeze my app (working continue only after exit).
Sending functions from DLL will called on worker thread only and I don't understand how can I proceed events and use that DLL in that case.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434948/1217285) to the duplicate question shows how to call `QCoreApplication::exec` in a separate thread from the main one so that it doesn't block the main thread.